# Open Cart Administrator Login

Tags: opencart

Im using Open Cart version 1.4.9.2. I was host this and working more than 6 months. It was working perfectly without any problem.

Few days before i try to login to admin panel, when i try the admin url

http://vsports.lk/admin/

showing the same homepage. I couldnt get the admin login form page. I dont no whats went wrong.

My Home page URL  http://vsports.lk/
Admin URL http://vsports.lk/admin/

Please if anyone can help on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It may be .htaccess  issue.

http://www.vsports.lk/admin/index.php

Comment: Thank You very much youur rite its htaccess issue only , do you have any idea to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the config.php under the admin folder

URL Like : http://website.url/admin